# Onclick delete table row jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a table that I can't seem to delete the rows from no matter what I try.
Its a simple table of 5 columns and a few rows generated from a php/mysql lookup using Json. I'd eventually like to delete the row from the mysql table with the button click but I'm stuck with the "easy" part of deleting the row in jquery.

Here is the code to create my table:

```
var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('tbc');
for (var i = 0; i < json.admin_tables.length; i++) {
var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('guid').attr('id', i).add('<td>' + json.admin_tables[i].Room + '</td><td>' + json.admin_tables[i].time + '</td><td>' + json.admin_tables[i].Desk + '</td><td>' + i + '</td><td><input type="button" id="'+ i + '" class="delete" value="Delete row ' + i + '"</td>');
table.append(row);
$('#roomTable').append(table);
}
```

The following code does nothing at all however (no errors in firebug)

```
$('.delete').click(function() { 
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
}
```

Changing "tr" to "td" will delete the button only and I don't want to have to delete every field individually!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.delete` elements are inserted dynamically, so you'll need delegated event handlers to target them:

```
$('#roomTable').on('click', '.delete', function() { 
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: nope adeneo doesn't do anything at all for me. I tried the empty() as well just to be sure. You can see it here: http://examtime.atwebpages.com/admintable.php

Comment: if you are using older jquery may need http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ instead of on. @adeneo thinking more on it i think it is just a speed thing. the remove was taking to long and by emptying it first it got faster for some reason.

Comment: I did try a few versions with delegate and live as well. I'm using 1.8.2 so not too old anyway

Comment: i did notice your doctype is invalid, think there is a typo in it. not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @user1569869 - Your markup is invalid, the `.delete` elements are'nt children of the `tr`'s, so there is no `closest('tr')` to remove. The errors originates from using `add()` and not `append()` when appending the `td`'s to the `tr`'s.

Comment: nice spot! I've fixed that but still no joy with the real problem

Comment: As a sidenote the click function should be moved out of the $.ajax function completely, and when setting the dataType to JSON, it parses it automagically, no need to use JSON.parse.

Comment: @adeneo perfect thanks I spent so long with different versions of the removal I missed the real problem